Implementing an Input Form with Webcam Integration in FilamentPHP Framework
I'm working on a project using FilamentPHP framework and need to implement an input form that integrates with a webcam for capturing images. Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this integration? Specifically, I'm looking for recommendations on libraries or methods within FilamentPHP that support webcam input for user forms.
I was hoping to find a straightforward method or library within FilamentPHP that facilitates webcam integration directly into a form. Alternatively, guidance on how to integrate a third-party PHP library for webcam capture into a FilamentPHP-based project would be greatly appreciated.
